# start unicorn app server when the ubuntu server starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I am running my rails application using ruby enterprise edition with unicorn as app server. I run this command

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/ubuntu/apps/st/config/unicorn.rb
```

I need to run this command soon after the system reboots or starts. I am running the app on ubuntu 10.04 LTS EC2 instance. I tried couple of examples which are mentioned [on this site](http://codetunes.com/2012/nginxunicorn-configuration-for-multi-app-servers) as well [as this site](http://robert-reiz.com/2012/02/29/running-unicorn-as-a-service-on-debian-linux/) but it’s not working for me. Any heads up

Comment: How is it not working? Do you see an error? Is the process not actually running (check with ps aux)

Comment: I added this script and reboot the instance but the unicorn was started also I checked syslog did not find and log and also checked ps aux, the process was not yet started yet

Comment: I need to run bundle exec, its not typically unicorn_rails. Make difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I just wanted it quick so I place the startup command in `/etc/rc.local` like below. Note that i'm using `RVM`.

```
# By default this script does nothing.
cd <your project dir>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/bundle exec unicorn -c <your project dir>/config/unicorn.conf -D
test -e /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key || dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
exit 0
```

Make sure your startup command is above the exit 0. After you reboot, check whether it is running or not by directly hitting the url of your application or use `ps -aux | grep unicorn` command.

Note* Previously I use Phusion Passenger but I'm having trouble to see its error log, so I move back to unicorn. I also tried @warantesbr without success, which I guess it fails because my whole environment where setup using root access.

Answer (score 16):

Try it as an Upstart. To do so, you need to create a **myapp.conf** file into the directory **/etc/init/** with the contents below:

```
description "myapp server"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown
exec sudo -u myuser sh -c "cd /path/to/my/app && bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/ubuntu/apps/st/config/unicorn.rb"

respawn
```

After that, you should be able to start/stop/restart your app with the commands below:

```
start myapp
stop myapp
restart myapp
```

Use **ps -aux | grep myapp** to check if your app is running.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: when run start myapp, its says unknown job.

Comment: I get: `initctl: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.7" (uid=1000 pid=4533 comm="initctl start staging-myapp ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")`

Comment: @MichieldeMare I'm sorry, but I'haven't got notified about your comment, so I've just got it. I think you could get some help [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153064/user-upstart-job-in-init-is-not-found). It seems to be the same error you've got.

Comment: @MaxKonin didn't know this gem. I'll try it as soon as i can. Thx!

Answer (score 14):

You can use [this file](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/init.sh) as a template, set appropriate paths mentioned in this file, make it executable and symlink into `/etc/init.d/my_unicorn_server`. Now you can start the server using:

```
sudo service my_unicorn_server start
```

Then you can do:

```
sudo update-rc.d my_unicorn_server defaults
```

To startup the unicorn server on system reboot automatically.

Comment: This is only recommended if you don't have upstart. I don't recall whether 10.04 does. Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: Works out of the box for me on 12.04.. Make sure while generating symlink you give absolute path and not relative..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using unicorn_init script 
You can configure a cron job to start the unicorn server on reboot

```
crontab -e
```

and add

```
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'service unicorn_<your service name> start >> /<path to log file>/cron.log 2>&1'
```